# Full Screen Video on Mobile Device

Tags: html, css, video, mobile

Shown below is the code I'm using for my website. I have a video that displays full screen when on a bigger screen and I'd like the video to play full screen on a mobile device as well (even if a portion of the video gets cut off).

If anyone knows of a way to make this happen, I'd appreciate you letting me know.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en; jp;">
<body>

<title>言語の選択 - Select Language</title> 
    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<video src="photos/Home_Page/Home/Home_Page.mp4" autoplay loop muted playsinline width="100%;" style="z-index: 100px; overflow: hidden;"></video>
 
<div class="relative">
<p style="text-align: left; font-size: 80px; font-family: sans-serif; overflow: hidden; color: transparent; opacity: .45;"><a href="Website_Home_Page.html" style="text-decoration:none; color: black; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 darkgray,-1px 1px 0 darkgray,1px -1px 0 darkgray,-1px -1px 0 darkgray;">小泉</a>
</div>

<div class="absolute">
<p style="text-align: left; font-size: 29px; font-family: sans-serif; overflow: hidden; color: transparent; opacity: .8;"><a href="Website_Home_Page.html" style="text-decoration:none; color: black; opacity: .8; text-shadow:.5px .5px 0 #fff,-.5px .5px 0 #fff,.5px -.5px 0 #fff,-.5px -.5px 0 #fff;">Koizumi</a>
</div>
    
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><p style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; font-family: sans-serif; overflow: hidden;"><a href="Website_Home_Page.html" style="text-decoration:none; color: white; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #000,-1px 1px 0 #000,1px -1px 0 #000,-1px -1px 0 #000;"><b>日本語 </b></a> |  <a href="Website_Home_Page_English.html" style="text-decoration:none; color: white; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #000,-1px 1px 0 #000,1px -1px 0 #000,-1px -1px 0 #000;"><b>English</b></a></p>   
    
<style>
    
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    left: 35px;
    top: 38px;
}
    
.video {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
} 
    
p {          
  color: white;
  text-decoration:none; color: white; text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #000,-1px 1px 0 #000,1px -1px 0 #000,-1px -1px 0 #000;
  font-size: 400%;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;}
 
    
      
</style>    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Resizing the video so that it fits into the viewport in both dimensions, is the usual definition of "fullscreen" - so you actually want something else here. Increasing the size of the video element itself so that it matches the viewport dimensions won't help, I think - then you'd just get black bars inside the element. You would probably have to go look for a solution using `object-fit`.

Comment: Object-fit seems to work well. Is there any way I can set the video so that it scales down to fit the size of the mobile screen?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the latter. (Sounds like the complete opposite of what you asked for initially?)

Comment: I know understand how to make the video fit the entire mobile screen, but major parts of the video I was looking to show got cut off. I was just wondering if there is any way to scale down the video so that it remains full screen but the image fits better.

Comment: Or are you asking how you can fit the `video` element itself into the screen dimensions, when the intrinsic dimensions of the video file are larger? Then try and specify `right:0` and `bottom:0` as well. (Not sure right now whether width and height would have to be set to auto, too, to overwrite the intrinsic dimensions.)